# MSP430FR5994 SVSH Interrupt from LPMx.5

Tags: low-power, msp430

Background:  I plan to use lpmx.5 under cap power but need a way to save the rtc registers to FRAM when the super-cap runs down.

Plan:  Use SYSRSTIV SVSH interrupt to wake up and save the counter, or use P5.6 to wake up if the power is restored.

Quote from manual:

> The following conditions will cause an exit from LPM4.5:
>
> - A wakeup event on an I/O if configured and enabled. The interrupt flag of the corresponding port pin is set (PxIFG). The PMMLPM5IFG bit is set.
> - A wakeup from the RST pin.
> - A power-cycle. Either the SVSHIFG or none of the PMMIFGs is set.
>
> Any exit from LPM4.5 causes a BOR. The program execution starts at the address the reset vector points
>   to. PMMLPM5IFG = 1 indicates a wakeup from LPM4.5, or the System Reset Vector Word register (SYSRSTIV) can be used to decode the reset condition (see the device data sheet).

and

Figure 2-2. Voltage Failure and Resulting PMM Actions not showing the power-down SVSH interrupt.

Revised questions:

1. Is the SVSH interrupt available at power-down between SVSH trigger
   and BOR reset?
2. How do I detect a SVSH wake-up?
3. If a need IO pin P5.6 wake up - Table 6-10 does not mention PMMLPM5 by name.  Is this the LPMx.5 wake-up or $08 vector and is
   this the specific one triggered by, say P5.6, if correctly
   configured?
4. Can the SVSH trigger be used to save the RTC counters RTCCNT12 AND RTCCNT34?  (see below)

I needed to split question 1 in two parts as I can confirm that SVSH can be used by sampling SYSRSTIV == 0x0E at startup.  However, when I read the counters under SVSH they always return zero.  I have also confirmed this strange behaviour by triggering SVSH from the active mode.

Is this a hardware bug?  I am testing the code with a Rev B chip.

Answer (score 1):

Section 2.2.4 of the User's Guide says:

> LPM3.5 and LPM4.5 can be configured with active SVS (SVSHE = 1) or with SVS disabled (SVSHE = 0). Disabling the SVS results in lower power consumption, whereas enabling it provides the ability to detect supply drops and getting a "wake-up" due to the supply drop below the SVS threshold.

and:

> the "wake-up" due to a supply failure would not be flagged as a LPMx.5 wake-up but as a SVS reset event.

Comment: Thanks for answering point 1.  Do you maybe have an answer for 2?

Comment: The second quote answers 2.

Comment: Part 3. added for clarity, (my bad)

Comment: SVSH is listed in table 6-10 of the datasheet.

Comment: Noted.  Part three is not applicable to SVSH.

Answer (score 0):

1- Usually your SVSH interrupt will occur when your voltage has dropped below threshold, but It will put you on BOR.
Refer to page 68 on this document: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau445i/slau445i.pdf

2- You will be woke up on BOR state. From BOR, if everything is fine, you will land on your main and be able to normally run your code. You should check for its register flag on the startup of your firmware.

3- Yes, you can wake from in any pin according to http://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR5994
"Edge-Selectable Wake From LPM on All Ports"

4- Yes, you can detect the the register flag being set on your startup and trigger a routine to save your desired variables.